# Is there a way to know when TypeScript compiling will finish the first building with "--watch" option?

Tags: typescript, shell, npm

The building of **Tokens** and **ModulesCollection** could be executed at the parallel while **Lexer** - once **Tokens** and **ModulesCollection** will be build for the first time. Below code is incorrect from `&` in `npm run "Incremental building" &` line:

```bash
cd UAA_Generators/JapaneseSyntax/ByNodeJS/DataStructures/Tokens || exit
npm run "Incremental building" &

cd ../ModulesCollection || exit
npm run "Incremental building" &

cd ../../Actuators/Lexer || exit
npm run "Incremental building"
```

The "Incremental building" script is same for each subproject:

```bash
rimraf Distributable & tsc --watch
```

The problem is because of `--watch` option the task will never end (until we kill this process). Can we know when first building of **Tokens** and **ModulesCollection** end?

Please note that I need the rebuilding on changes so the disabling of `--watch` option is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be optimal, but I'd look into writing a custom build script for this use case. Use either vanilla Node.js, Gulp, or Grunt; but I recommend Gulp.

Fundamentally, a dependent shell command waiting on an independent one via `&` will never execute if the independent command never ends. To support parallelism, these commands must run in separate non-blocking terminals, as separate processes.

Typescript's provides official documentation on [configuring `--watch`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/configuring-watch.html) and how you can use [Gulp with Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html).

`--watch` just uses `fs.watch` and `fs.watchFile` under the hood.

Theoretically, you could use Gulp's [watch()](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch/) and [parallel()](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/parallel/) to achieve the build behavior you want.

---

Otherwise, it's a question of achieving parallelism with pure Shell scripting with commands that never end... It could get messy between invoking child processes or etc.